# how do i sum two variables in for each loop or while or for loop

Tags: php, variables, sum

is that possible to sum variable static values in the while or for loop? i have code and working on it but it sum variables only one time?

**Here My Code**

```
session_start();

$length=count($_SESSION['product1']);   

$shipping2='280';
$shipping3='680';
$newshipping='0';
$newshipping1='0';
$i='0';

while($i= <$length)
{
$newshipping=$shipping2+$shipping3;
$newshipping1=$newshipping+$shipping2;
}
```

**For Example I want like this**

`$shipping2='280';` should be sum with every result of `$newshipping1`

```
`$newshipping1`= $shipping2='280' + $shipping3='680' = `$newshipping1`=960 
 +  $shipping2='280'??

'$newshipping1`=960+ $shipping2=280+ $shipping2=280+ $shipping2=280 ..... 
 when ever new product1 enter it should be add  $shipping2=280 
 in the result of `$newshipping1`
```

**I have completed my code here my final code**

```
$length=count($_SESSION['product1']);   
$shipping2=280;
$shipping3=680;
$newshipping=0;
for($i=0; $i <$length; $i++) {
if($i == 1) { 
$newshipping = $shipping2+$shipping3; 
} else if($i <= 100) {
$newshipping = $newshipping+$shipping2;
}
}
```

Comment: use integers for math operations: `$a = 1;` instead of `$a = '1';`

Comment: i dont really understand what you want. but it seems you are looking for the += operator... $newshipping1 += $shipping2;

Comment: @steven lets assume we have a and values so `a=680 and b=280 and c=a+b now c=960 values now new product enter into the shopping cart then c=960+280 again and again when ever new product entered into the shopping cart`?

Comment: that means: if you have a count of 5 it is ((680+280) + (4 * 280)). is this correct?

Comment: @steven one product in shipping cost is `680` and when second product entered into the shipping cost is '280' now shipping cost should be `680+280=960` when third product enter into shopping cart then automatically shipping cost will be increase like `960+280=1240` and when ever new product entered into cart `1240+280=1520' ??? same thing i want to do ??

Comment: @steve i want to know how do i get `$shipping2='280';` in the loop?

Comment: @steven now this correct what i want to do `f you have a count of 5 it is ((680+280)=960) + (5 * 280)=1400+960). this is correct`

Comment: @user2419956 please check out my last answer this should give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems a bit confusing, however you can sum several integers. If you are trying to figure out the final amount of several iterations you should:

```
$shipping_one = 680;
$shipping_two = 260;
$shipping_three = 0;
$finalShipping = array();

while($i= <$length)
{   
    $finalShipping[] = $shipping_one + $shipping_two + $shipping_three;
}

$finalTotal = array_sum($finalShipping);
```

If you can clarify your question, I can clarify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

this will be ((680) + (4 * 280)) like you explained in your last comment.

```
$length = 1;
echo "Test with $length : ".getShippingTotal($length)." <br />";

$length = 2;
echo "Test with $length : ".getShippingTotal($length)." <br />";

$length = 3;
echo "Test with $length : ".getShippingTotal($length)." <br />";

$length = 4;
echo "Test with $length : ".getShippingTotal($length)." <br />";

$length = 5;
echo "Test with $length : ".getShippingTotal($length)." <br />";

function getShippingTotal($length) {

    $shipping2=280;
    $shipping3=680;
    $total = 0;

    for($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) {
      if($i == 0) { 
          $total += $shipping2+$shipping3; 
      } else {
          $total += $shipping2;
      }
    }
    return $total;
}
```

I have tested it and it gave me:

```
Test with 1 : 960 
Test with 2 : 1240 
Test with 3 : 1520 
Test with 4 : 1800 
Test with 5 : 2080
```

Comment: let me try it but $length=count($_SESSION['product1']);

Comment: have you copied the code into a new test.php file? Ive tested and it works. Undefined function?? have you copied the function? not into a class!

Comment: @user2419956 if it is working in test.php you can copy the code inside the function and replace it with your old code. Try to understand what happens there and it will be easy to modify it for your special case.